# How to restrict user to enter only two digits for Integer Field in gxt/gwt

Tags: gwt, gxt

I want to restricted the user not to enter more than two digits into Inetger Field in gxt

Answer (score 1):

Setting the maxlength attribute of a DOM input text element is possible, but I would use the things that comes with GXT:

```
NumberField<Integer> nf = new NumberField<Integer>(new IntegerPropertyEditor());
nf.addValidator(new MaxNumberValidator<Integer>(99));
```

Any number greater than 99 will marked as error.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for GWT :

```
IntegerBox box  = new IntegerBox();
box.getElement().setAttribute("maxlength", "2");
```

Also works with TextBox objects. I guess it also works with every widget which is representet in HTML with an input tag.